# One button to select 2 files and put the result in two text fields in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have these 2 functions:

```py
def browsefunc1():
    filename =filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("rpt files","*.rpt"),("All files","*.*")))
    inputtxt1.insert(tkinter.END, filename)

def browsefunc2():
    filename =filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("fss files","*.fss"),("All files","*.*")))
    inputtxt5.insert(tkinter.END, filename)
```

and these 2 buttons:

```py
fileButton=tkinter.Button(window,text="Select File",command=browsefunc1)
fileButton.pack()
fileButton.place(x=540, y=78)
fileButton2=tkinter.Button(window,text="Select File",command=browsefunc2)
fileButton2.pack()
fileButton2.place(x=540, y=298)
```

I want to use only one button for both functions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new function that calls the other 2 functions -

```
def call_func():
    browsefunc1() # This function happens before the next
    browsefunc2()
```

Then -

```
fileButton = tkinter.Button(window,text="Select File",command=call_func)
```

Do not use `.pack` if you want to use `.place`. Any one of them is ok -

```
fileButton2=tkinter.Button(window,text="Select File",command=browsefunc2)
fileButton2.pack() # Remove this 
fileButton2.place(x=540, y=298) # Or this
```

Comment: Is there another way to not select the 2 files at the same time ? since inputtxt5 is appeared only after combo box selection which happens after choosing the first file